# Passing custom props to component with redux-form 7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using the following libraries

```
"@material-ui/core": "^3.0.3",
"react": "^16.5.0",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux-form": "^7.4.2",
```

How do I pass custom props to my `component` property of the redux-form `<Field />`?

According to [this example](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/material-ui/) from redux-form everything I have below should work, but it is not pulling the `multiline={true}` or `rows={2}` props into the `<TextField />` component.

I am not sure how it is supposed to work as I am a novice with javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

PostForm.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'


class PostForm extends React.Component {

  renderTextField = ({ input,
                      label, 
                      meta: { error, touched } },
                      ...custom) => {
    return (
        <TextField
          name={label}
          label={label}
          {...input}
          {...custom}
        />
    );
  };


  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { submitPost, history, formValues } = this.props;

    submitPost(formValues.values, history);
  }

  render() {
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>

      <Field 
        name="title"
        component={this.renderTextField}
        label="Title"
      />
      <Field 
        name="body"
        component={this.renderTextField}
        label="Body"
        multiline={true}
        rows={2}
      />
      <div className={classes.buttonContainer}>
        <Button to="/posts" component={Link} className={classes.button} color='secondary'>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button type='submit' className={classes.button} color='primary'>
          Next
        </Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'postForm',
  destroyOnUnmount: false
})(PostForm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render multi line fields, you need to pass `multiLine={true}` (notice the camel casing - this is important). This is based on docs linked from https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui which seem like old version. According to newer docs, it seems `multiline` is all lowercase (leaving it here for posterity's sake).

**Update**

Also, `...custom` is outside of the curly braces. Should be

```
renderTextField = ({ input, label, meta: { error, touched } , ...custom })
```

A bit about how `Field` passes props down - it's not enough to cover everything in this answer but I can give a few pointers to help you get started.

`<Field ... />` is JSX notation. While JSX makes it easy to read and wirte HTML constructs, `[React actually doesn't need JSX][1]`. Internally, they all compile to pure JS functions (using `React.createElement` and other factory functions).

After that, passing `...custom` etc. is just [rest/spread operators](https://www.eventbrite.com/engineering/learning-es6-rest-spread-operators/) introduced in ES6. They are shortcuts, and you can use React without them as well (meaning you can use just ES5 syntax).

Comment: I agree with Mrchief.

Comment: According to the docs, multiline is [all lowercase](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/). Furthermore, The ‘multiline’ prop will work if passed directly to the TextField component.

Comment: It wasn't when I copy/pasted that little code block - from the docs - yesterday.

Comment: Oh I see. I went to https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field which is linked from https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui which is linked from the "the example" link that OP has posted.

Comment: Also, it is being passed to `TextField` via `{...custom}`

Comment: @Mrchief the {...custom} isn’t being passed in it seems

Comment: If it's getting populated, then it should. That's just JavaScript - unless you rely on babel and missing a transform or plugin... I'd do a console.log and see if I'm getting the desired props in `custom`

Comment: I did a console.log(custom) in the function renderTextField and it is logging an object with an empty array

Comment: Oh now I see the typo: `...custom` is outside of the curly braces. Should be `renderTextField = ({ input, label, meta: { error, touched } ,  ...custom })`

Comment: Awesome! That worked. You should put this in your answer and I will accept it. Still, I don't understand the inner workings of reactjs and how the javascript takes those props in ```<Field />``` and passes them into the component function. However, I'll take the win.

Comment: Done. Also tried to explain the internals a bit in the answer. See my updates.